# Remove punctuations from list and convert string value to float in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, training-data, punctuation

I want to remove the dollar signs and commas from the column and cast to float.
This is what I do so far, it didn't work. Actually nothing changed.
The data look like["$200,00","$1,000.00"..."$50.00"]

```
import pandas as pd
import string
y_train = train.iloc[:,-1]
needtoclean=y_train.to_list()#''.join(y_train.to_list())

to_delete = set(string.punctuation) - {'$',','} 
clean = [x for x in needtoclean if x not in to_delete]
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a code sample with your question. That makes it easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list_ = ['$58.00', '$60.00']       #Your Lise
new_list = []                      #Initialise new list
for elem in list_:                 #Iterate over previous list's elements
    elem = elem.replace("$", '')   #Replace the `$` sign
    new_list.append(float(elem))   #Add the typecasted float to new list
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, next time you should post code

Iterate list by index to be able to modify values.

1). Remove $

2). Cast to float

```
for i in xrange(len(your_list)):
    your_list[i] = float(your_list[i].replace("$", ""))
```

Comment: the dollar sign cannot be replaced.

Comment: Why you said that??

Answer (score 0):

If dollar signs always in the same place in those strings this should do the job.
I assumpt that you use pandas dataframe.

```
df["needtoclean"] = df["needtoclean"].apply(lambda x: float(x[1:].replace(",", "")))
```

Comment: It worked but I also have an observation"1,000" that has a comma in it, It cannot be cast to float

Answer (score 0):

It would be easily solved as list comprehenshion.

```py
unclean = ['$58.00', '$125.00']  # your data
clean = [float(value[1:]) for value in unclean if value.startswith('$')]
# you can remove "if value.startswith('$')" if you are sure 
# that all values start with $
```

If you want it as function:

```py
unclean = ['$58.00', '$125.00']

def to_clean_float(unclean):
    return [float(value[1:]) for value in unclean if value.startswith('$')]

print(to_clean_float(unclean))  # Gives: [58.0, 125.0]
```

If you don't need it as atomic list but want to work further with the data, you could also create a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).
If it's a huge list it can save a lot of memory.

```py
unclean = ['$58.00', '$125.00']

def to_clean_float(unclean):
    return (float(value[1:]) for value in unclean if value.startswith('$'))

clean_generator = to_clean_float(unclean)
print(list(value for value in clean_generator))  # Gives: [58.0, 125.0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The data also involves commas. Some of them cannot be cast to float.

Comment: I'm not a fan of an approach based on indexes. `[float(value.replace("$", "").replace(",", ".")) for value in unclean]` is more robust in my opinion.